# Shift a number to the beginning of a string recursive Java

Tags: java, recursion

The task is to shift a number within a string to the beginning of the string with a recursion. So if I feed "ba3nana" to the code it should return "3banana". Did some recursive tasks already but this one I am stuck on. 
I tried I guess already 50 different combinations but so far my code only returns "banana3" so I go the opposite way with my number. Does anyone see the mistake in my code?

The call of the method looks like this:

```
System.out.println(shiftDigitLeft("ba3nana"));
```

This is the code so far:

```
private static String shiftDigitLeft(String text) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text.charAt(0) >= '\u0030' && text.charAt(0) <= '\u0039') {
                return shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0);
            } else {
                return text.charAt(0) + shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're building the string backwards

Comment: You should use `Character.isDigit()`  to check if the character is a digit.

Comment: Can the string contain only one digit? And if not what is the expected output for `ban32ana`

Comment: I was trying several times to build the string up the other way. The code I put here was one that did at least something in terms of shifting the digit. If I reverse it I get the result 3ananab.

Comment: For this example the test strings only contain 1 digit.

Answer (score 2):

The pseudocode for what you've written would look like this

```
String shiftDigitLeft(String text) {
    if the text is empty
        return empty
    else
        if the first character is a digit
             return shiftDigitLeft(the rest of the string) + the digit
        else
             return the letter + shiftDigitLeft(the rest of the string)
}
```

It should be obvious from this that digits never get moved to the left, only to the right.

You should probably invert your approach so that you look whether the *last* character is a digit, and if it is then move it to the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so far! I see what you mean but still cannot figure out the right combination to get the right output. If I shift things around everything gets reversed to become "3ananab"